# Execute function after window replace

Tags: javascript, dom, angularjs

I send request with `angular.js` with `$http` and got some response and after that i must update page and call `timer` function:

```
$http({method: 'POST', url: url_api, data: {login_username: username, login_password: password}}).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
 // parse data
 ....
 window.location.replace("/");
 // call timer
 timer();
}
```

Where `timer`:

```
function timer(){
  document.getElementById("span_count_down").innerHTML = 'Time is out!';
  return;
}
```

But when i update page, i don't see `Time is out!` in `innerHTML`, i see previous `innerHTML`.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

When you call `location.replace()`, the page is unloaded and no further script is executed. When the new page loads, your script is not executed because it wasn't called on this page.